# Oracle SQL Case statement in JOIN ON condition

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to have a case statement in the JOIN ON statement for Oracle SQL?

I have tried:

```
SELECT * from table_a JOIN table_b 
ON table_a.id = table_b.table_a_fk_id
AND CASE WHEN table_a.field_1 is not null 
THEN table_a.field_1 = table_b.field_1 
ELSE
1=1
END;
```

But I am getting error:

> ORA-00905: missing keyword at = sign on line 4

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a **case expression** can be used in joins it really isn't required here, boolean logic can be used instead.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
JOIN table_b
    ON table_a.id = table_b.table_a_fk_id
        AND (
            table_a.field_1 = table_b.field_1
            OR table_a.field_1 IS NULL
            )
```

The assumption is that you want to use both table_a_fk_id & field_1 when field_1 is available, but to still join via table_a_fk_id alone when field_1  is null.

---

As an aside a "case statement" is actually part of pl/sql used for branching. The syntax is similar but what you can do with a case statement is vastly different to what a **case expression** does.